# Add SUM to SQL Server Query Results

Tags: sql-server-2014

I need to add a `SUM` function to the bottom of my SQL Server query results.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT 
    STATE, COUNTY, NAME, STNAME, CENSUS2010POP, ESTIMATESBASE2010
FROM 
    [CensusData].[dbo].[SUB-EST2014_ALL]
WHERE 
    (SUMLEV = '50') 
    AND (CENSUS2010POP > 100000) 
    AND (CENSUS2010POP < 200000)
```

After reading several posts and blogs about this I updated my query to the following:

```
SELECT 
    STATE, COUNTY, NAME = ISNULL(NAME, 'Total'), STNAME, 
    CENSUS2010POP = SUM(CENSUS2010POP), ESTIMATESBASE2010
FROM 
    [CensusData].[dbo].[SUB-EST2014_ALL]
WHERE 
    (SUMLEV = '50') 
    AND (CENSUS2010POP > 100000) 
    AND (CENSUS2010POP < 200000)
GROUP BY 
    ROLLUP(NAME)
```

However when I try to run the modified query I get an error:

> Column 'CensusData.dbo.SUB-EST2014_ALL.STATE' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I have never used the `SUM` function in SQL Server so I am not sure what this error means or what it will take to fix it.

Can someone pinpoint my error and tell me what it will take to fix it? I am running SQL Server 2014.

Comment: Everything except the SUM column in your select list needs to be in the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you could probably get the rollup to work, perhaps this is the easiest fix for what I think you want:

```
SELECT STATE, COUNTY, NAME, STNAME, CENSUS2010POP, ESTIMATESBASE2010, '' AS Aggregated
FROM [CensusData].[dbo].[SUB-EST2014_ALL]
WHERE (SUMLEV = '50') AND (CENSUS2010POP > 100000) AND (CENSUS2010POP < 200000)
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, SUM(CENSUS2010POP), SUM(ESTIMATESBASE2010), 'Total'
FROM [CensusData].[dbo].[SUB-EST2014_ALL]
WHERE (SUMLEV = '50') AND (CENSUS2010POP > 100000) AND (CENSUS2010POP < 200000)
ORDER BY Aggregated
```

Technically the extra row might not appear at the bottom so I had to add an extra column to force the sort.

Here's the way to do it with grouping sets. Since you only seem to want the grand totals I don't believe `rollup` would work unless maybe you concatenated the four values into a single computed column.

```
SELECT
    STATE, COUNTY, NAME, STNAME,
    sum(CENSUS2010POP) as CENSUS2010POP,
    sum(ESTIMATESBASE2010) as ESTIMATESBASE2010)
FROM [CensusData].[dbo].[SUB-EST2014_ALL]
WHERE (SUMLEV = '50') AND (CENSUS2010POP > 100000) AND (CENSUS2010POP < 200000)
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((STATE, COUNTY, NAME, STNAME), ())
ORDER BY GROUPING(STATE)
```

Comment: both of these are giving me the same error message:

Comment: I noticed that you didn't actually want to sum the `ESTIMATESBASE2010` column. What is the error and what is that a numeric column?

Comment: sorry was trying to edit that message and session timedout: Operand data type varchar is invalid for sum operator. it is erroring out on the FROM statement

Comment: adding the sum to ESTIMATESBASE2010 is fine, i will likely need that data for some calculations.

Comment: It sounds like those columns are character type. Assuming the data is valid you can use `sum(cast(<column> as numeric(13, 3)))`. I'm guessing at the type since you haven't specified.

Comment: that is accurate. i imported this data from several CSV files. the columns should be all numeric but there was data integrity issues that prevented the import unless i designated the datatype as string [DT_STR] which ultimately cast the column as varchar.

Comment: that solution works perfectly now. thanks for the help.

Comment: using the last suggestion you made, sum(cast(<column> as numeric(13,3))) makes both of the queries work. since they both work now, is one of the queries a better method than the other? i will be running this query against several hundred thousand data points so i need to consider which method is most efficient.

Comment: Grouping sets probably.